# How to consume latest message on button click and write it to the txt file?

Tags: c#, .net, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-platform

I've wrote a simple producer that send on button click a message to the Kafka.

```
class Producer : IProducer
{
    public void produce(string msg, string topic)
    {
        var config = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            {"bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092" }
        };

        using (var producer = new Producer<Null, string>(config, null, new StringSerializer(Encoding.UTF8)))
        {
             var m = producer.ProduceAsync(topic, null, msg).Result;
        }
    }
}
```

My question is - how to write a consumer that will raise on button click and receive latest posted message from Kafka and save it to a txt file somewhere on local disk? This is what I wrote for now:

```
public class Consumer
{
    public void Consume(string topic)
    {
        var config = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            {"group.id", "consumer-latest-msg" },
            {"bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092" },
            {"auto.commit.interval.ms", 5000 },
            {"auto.offset.reset", "latest" }
        };

        using (var consumer = new Consumer<Null, string>(config, null, new StringDeserializer(Encoding.UTF8)))
        {
                //what to do?
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: Just a disclaimer before I start writing the answer: I'm not familiar with C#, so I'll try and answer this conceptually.

I think all you need to do inside your consumer space is:

1. Subscribe to the topic by invoking the `subscribe()` method of the consumer
2. Invoke the `poll()` method of the consumer --> This will return the newly written record(s)
3. Process all records in a loop i.e. package each message (key and/or value) in a new file as required.

I tried this quickly in Java and here is the code snippet (containing the 3 mentioned steps) for your reference:

```
consumer.subscribe(Collections.singleton("test-topic"));

    try {
        while (true) {
            ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(1000);
            for(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {

                fWriter = new FileWriter("data/msg-" + i++);
                pWriter = new PrintWriter(fWriter);
                pWriter.print(record.value());
                pWriter.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        consumer.close();
    }
```

On Running this consumer client and producing a couple of messages from the console producer, 2 files were created in the specified directory (data).

Also, the reason for the infinite loop is to ensure that the consumer just keeps running because if the consumer doesn't poll regularly, then the Consumer Group Coordinator assumes that the consumer has died and a re-balance is triggered within the consumer group.

I hope this helps!